# C# web service serialization of object properties

Tags: c#, serialization, service, properties, web

I have an instance of System.Web.Services.WebService with a [WebMethod] returning an instance of class A. Class A is defined below. I would like the property a to be serialized but it is not. It seems only fields are serialized. Is there any way to force the property to be serialized?

```
public class A
{
    private string _a;
    public string a { get { return _a; } }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialization requires that both the Setter and the Getter accessors are present.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string A { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way to avoid using a "dummy" setter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with dummy setter.   `public string A {get; set;}` actually expands to `private string _a;  public string A {get{return _a;} set{_a = value;}}`

Comment: dummy setter would be just `set { }`

Comment: A dummy setter would allow you to serialize the class, but generally speaking, if you need to deserialize it, that particular property would obviously not have the value set during deserialization.